# Scraping web page loaded through AngularJS - CURL PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, curl, phantomjs, casperjs

I have to scrape a webpage that is loaded using AngularJS. I am using CURL and PHP.

In CURL response I get the HTML of page which is prior to HTML produced by AngularJS.

I have Googled and got CasperJS and PhantomJS as a solution, I tried using PhantomJS and CasperJS but facing many issues.

Is there a way other than CasperJS and Phantom JS?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Casper and Phantom are a good solution - what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is Downvoted?
Anyways I completed my task using Phantom.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Can you please share your code